# Node How to load an image in pure html file in node?

Tags: node.js, path

I have researched by all I read was related when loading html inside a node js file. I have a pure .html file and want to load an image. How can I use a relative path inside?

I cannot put this into my script tag:

```
  const path = require('path');
    const jsonPath = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'resources', 'logo.png');
```

resources/email.html:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<img src="./logo.png">
    <p>Hello</p>
<script>
    const path = require('path');
    const jsonPath = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'resources', 'logo.png');
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: "path" package is only available to nodejs not browsers. So its not possible. if you want load image data in js you have to make http request.

Comment: so i cannot just keep the img file in my folder and access it somehow in my html file like i would if the html file wouldnt be in my backend?

Comment: can you exmplain what are you trying to achieve / whats this project is about ?? so I can give clear answer.